# Dart SASS Guide: What is 'using ($type)'?

Tags: css, sass

From the snippet from the SASS documentation [LINK](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#passing-arguments-to-content-blocks) I can't seem to find information on what the code `using ($type)` means.

```
@mixin media($types...) {
  @each $type in $types {
    @media #{$type} {
      @content($type);
    }
  }
}

@include media(screen, print) using ($type) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    @if $type == print {
      font-family: Calluna;
    }
  }
}
```

What does `using ($type)` mean / do ?  Is it part of the SASS language or is it part of another bigger language?

Comment: No, it is not part of SASS. It is a variable you choose. It could be $items or anything else. It could be anything, in this instance it is proper in showing what the mixin is doing. There is supposed to be an array named $types. Consult the SASS documentation  https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each

Comment: yes, I know '$type' is simply a given name of an array, but where is the documentation on the 'using' keyword?

Comment: its right above where you copied your example. A mixin can pass arguments to its content block the same way it would pass arguments to another mixin by writing content(<arguments...>). The user writing the content block can accept arguments by writing include <name> using (<arguments...>). The argument list for a content block works just like a mixin’s argument list, and the arguments passed to it by @content work just like passing arguments to a mixin.

Comment: Thank you.  I misunderstood the 'using' in that sentence as an English sentence context, instead correctly understanding it as a coding keyword.  *Face Palm* Dark Mode making the text coloring contrast too hard to detect didn't help. all good, thanks again